# Difference between na.rm = TRUE and na.action = na.omit in aggregate()

Tags: r, aggregate-functions, na

I had a dataset with NA values in there randomly, and when I use this:

```
aggregate(y2_predict[,15:17], list(Name=y2_predict$Name), mean, na.action = na.omit)
```

It gives something like this:

```
Name var1 Var2 Var3 
1999  NA    NA
2000 NA NA
2001 NA NA
```

But if I use this:

```
aggregate(y2_predict[,15:17], list(Name=y2_predict$Name), mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Then it returns something like this

```
Name var1 Var2 Var3 
1999  2    3.5
2000 5.2 6
2001 7 8
```

Apparently the first one does not work and the second one does. But I keep thinking they're mostly the same -- ignore NAs, or remove NAs ---neither of them should include NAs when calculating means by group. Then why is the first one not working? I am just making sure I'm not missing anything and I'm doing things correctly. Thanks.

Comment: The `na.action` is mostly useful for the formula method where it will remove an entire row if the `na.omit` is specified, while `na.rm` will remove only the NA values for the column of interest

Comment: The argument `na.action` is ignored when the first argument of `aggregate` is a `data.frame`. See `?aggregate`.

Comment: @nicola so do you mean that whenever there is an NA value in the column of interest then the mean function will return NA anyways? Just to make sure I can trust the second approach....Thanks!